# Life of a Java Object

Tags: java, object, object-lifetime

What is the life of a Java Object that is passed a method argument?

For example I have an object Test

```
class Test{

    public string testType(){
       .....
    }
}
```

and I have two classes A and B

```
class classA{

   classB b = new classB();

   void nextQuestion{
      b.start(new Test());
   }
}




class classB{
   void start(Test test){
      doSomething(test.testType());
   }
}
```

so now what is the life of the Test object? Is it only till the end of the start method or will it be alive till the end of classB or while it alive till the end of classA or is something else.

Comment: It would live until at least the `start()` method finished executing, there is _no_ guarantee about object lifetimes in Java since memory is managed by the garbage collecter and not the programmer.

Answer (score 6):

It will stay *atleast* till the end of `start()` method, because it has been declared there, and that is its scope. Beyond that, its existence is in the hands of the garbage collector.

---

EDIT:

By end of `start()` I mean, till that method ends it's execution. And even if you make the changes that you have shown, that `Object` is still needed by the `start()` method, so it will still only exist atleast till the execution of `start()` method is over, beyond that it depends on the garbage collector.

Comment: *at least* until the end of `start()`.

Comment: Yup. Silly mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Its life begins when `new Test()` is called, and it may be released by the garbage collector any time after the `start` method finishes, because it is provable at compile time that it will never be used after that point.

If the `start` method were to (for example) set a static field to refer to the object, the garbage collector could not collect it until that reference was released:

```
private static Test lastTested;
...

void start(Test test){
   lastTested = test;
   doSomething(test.testType());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The exact lifetime is determined by the garbage collector: once there are no more references to the object it can be reclaimed by the GC.  In your case it will live until at least the end of `ClassB.start()` as there are no more references to if once that method finished